# How to mock LocalView<TEntity>

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, moq

In my code I check the Local property of a DbSet to see what entities have already been added to the DbContext but not committed to the database yet.  I now need to Mock this property but it would appear that I can't.  This means when I test my code, it fails because the Local property is null.  Any ideas how I can do this?  I've added the code I'm currently using to generate the mock dbset below and this includes the code for generating the LocalView but this fails with a NotImplementedException() when you call the constructor.

I'm using the latest version of .Net Core and Entity Framework.

Cheers
Mark

```
var localDbSet = new Mock<DbSet<TEntity>>();
var localList = new List<TEntity>().AsQueryable();
var mockDbSet = new Mock<DbSet<TEntity>>();
var queryableData = list.AsQueryable();

localDbSet.As<IQueryable<TEntity>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(localList.Provider);
localDbSet.As<IQueryable<TEntity>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(localList.Expression);
localDbSet.As<IQueryable<TEntity>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(localList.ElementType);
localDbSet.As<IQueryable<TEntity>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(localList.GetEnumerator());

mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<TEntity>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(queryableData.Provider);
mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<TEntity>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(queryableData.Expression);
mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<TEntity>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(queryableData.ElementType);
mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<TEntity>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(queryableData.GetEnumerator());
mockDbSet.Setup(d => d.Add(It.IsAny<TEntity>()));

// This fails with a NotImplementedException
var localView = new LocalView<TEntity>(localDbSet.Object);
mockDbSet.Setup(d => d.Local).Returns(localView);
```

Comment: EF Core allows you to use an in-memory provider for testing. You are trying to test the behaviour of DbContext and LocalView itself so mocking them wouldn't help

Comment: Not an answer to the question as asked: that seems an awful lot of work for mocking and in the end only tests whether you have set up you mocks correctly. Consider using an In-Memory database instead of mocking all the intricate details of your database. That way you will also test if it actually works.

Comment: Why use a local view though? Why should your code care whether some entities were stored? When you call `SaveChanges` EF will persist all changes. Are you writing an interceptor?

Comment: BTW EF Core also provides a SQLite provider that can be used to test constraints, echecks etc that can't be tested with the in-memory provider. SQLite can be configured for in-memory operation too.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos In my code, I have to iterate through the Local collection to see what I have added to the context but not yet committed to the database.  Its a logic encapsulation thing.  I pull from the database, and then also check any updated but not committed changes I have made before making further changes prior to submitting back to the database.  I think the in memory database may be my only way forward.

Comment: I've now swapped to an InMemory database and this has resolved the issues I was seeing.  Only minor issue I had was the database not clearing down after each scenario but this was resolved by calling DbContext.Database.EnsureDeleted();